# Sentinelsat 0.12 Python

Tags: qgis, python, satellite, sentinel-2, photos

I am a beginner with computer programming  and I trying to use Python pack, sentinel-sat 0.12, to download images of Sentinel 2, but I get back a response I don't understand:

> sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 500 Internal Server
>   Error: IOException : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:30333//solr/dhus/select?q=beginposition:[2017-08-01T00:00:00Z%20TO%202017-08-30T00:00:00Z]%20cloudcoverpercentage:[0%20,%20100]%20platformname:Sentinel-2%20footprint:"Intersects(POLYGON((16.6085%2038.8957,16.6221%2039.4901,17.2206%2039.4802,17.2020%2038.8860,16.6085%2038.8957)))"&wt=xslt&tr=opensearch_atom.xsl&dhusLongName=Sentinels+Scientific+Data+Hub&dhusServer=https%3A%2F%2Fscihub.copernicus.eu%2Fdhus%2F&originalQuery=beginPosition%3A%5B2017-08-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2017-08-30T00%3A00%3A00Z%5D+cloudcoverpercentage%3A%5B0+%2C+100%5D+platformname%3ASentinel-2+footprint%3A%22Intersects%28POLYGON%28%2816.6085+38.8957%2C16.6221+39.4901%2C17.2206+39.4802%2C17.2020+38.8860%2C16.6085+38.8957%29%29%29%22&rows=100&start=0&sort=ingestiondate+desc

The script I have used is:

```
from sentinelsat.sentinel import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
api = SentinelAPI('**********', '*********','https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

# search by polygon, time, and SciHub query keywords
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('KR_REFEFA_POLY_extent_4326.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20170801', '20170830'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = '[0 , 100]')
```

The GeoJSON file SRC is in WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

I hope can you help me with this problem.

Comment: Thanks Bera, but if I try writing date in this way the program respond me to define date: name 'date' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `cloudcoverpercentage = '[0 , 100]'` to `cloudcoverpercentage = (0,100)` With this your code works for me:

```
from sentinelsat.sentinel import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
api = SentinelAPI('username', 'password','https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

# search by polygon, time, and SciHub query keywords
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('C:/path/area.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20170801','20170830'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,100))
```

I dont know why though. According to the [Sentinelsat Documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/sentinelsat/master/sentinelsat.pdf) your way should also work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an error in the `sentinelsat` documentation. The [.query()](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/api.html#sentinelsat.SentinelAPI.query) documentation is correct. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/159) for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This was an error in the `sentinelsat` documentation. As of version `0.12` parameter ranges should be provided as tuples.

Most commonly this is used in the `date=(<start>, <end>)` and `cloudcoverpercentage=(<min>, <max>)` parameters.

The error in the documentation has been [fixed](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/pull/161) and the latest version of the docs is correct: http://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html